# A way to set up virtual environment directly in Eclipse for Django project?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, virtual-environment

Is there a way to have Eclipse directly set up a virtual environment for Django? I can create one independently and import into Eclipse but wondering if there is a way to have Eclipse/PyDev set one up internally? Using Python 2.7 and/or 3.5, Django, Eclipse Mars and Virtualenv. Have searched python, eclipse, and django forums.

edited to add prior search history.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could be useful: http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com.ar/2011/07/django-setting-up-django-virtual.html